# Как узнать количество секунд от начала суток?

Tags: php, cookie, дата, время

```
{setcookie('date', $date, time()+(86400-_______колво_секуд_от_00:00_______), '/');
```

по серверу, конечно же.

Comment: Из текущего unixtime вычесть unixtime для начала дня - получите число секунд от начала дня.

Comment: Вам легче туда поставить время на начало следующих суток по совету Владимира Мартьянова.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Так проще всего:

```
echo time() - strtotime('today');
```

Answer (score 3):

Как-то так:

```
<?php
    $time = getdate();
    echo $second_passed = $time['seconds'] + 60*$time['minutes'] + 3600*$time['hours'];
?>
```

Comment: отлично! спасибо за разъяснения!